# (python) parsing xml file but the elements ends with \

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Good evening, i have to work on a xml file, the problem is that the elements in the file ends with a different format than usual, for example:

<1ELEMENT>
text
<\1ELEMENT>

I use the function `root=etree.parse('filepath')`, and, by changing manually in the text out of the compiler the \ in /, the function works correctly.
The big problem is that i need to automate that replacing process and the only solution that i thinked about is importing the file as array make a replace / to \ and build a new xml file;but it seems a little bit clunky.
Summing up i need to know if exist a function to replace the terms i mentioned above before to use the `root=etree.parse('filepath')`.

Comment: How is the file created? Instead of modifying the reader, you should repair the writer.

Comment: Element names can not start with a number if you expect to produce a valid XML. You should fix the XML producer first.

Comment: If it doesn't comply with the XML format specification, you *aren't* parsing an XML file.

Comment: I know the best thing to do would be to fix the problem at the origin but i haven't access to the source of this data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could

1. load the file
2. do the replacement, e.g.

   `string_containing_modified_data = data_as_string.replace('\\>', '/>')`
3. use `etree.fromstring(string_containing_modified_data)` to parse the xml.

If possible, you should try to fix the writer, but I understand if you don't have the opportunity to do so.

Comment: many thanks but i have one more question, i've tried this way but the replace mode doesn't accept the terms '/' or '</ '.

Comment: Hmmm. In your original question there is no such case... did you mean "\"? In this case you'll have to use an escape sequence "\\" instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [[w3]: Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml), your *XML* is not well formed:

- Invalid end tags - as you noticed, they should start with `/` not `\` ([[w3]: ETag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-ETag))
- Invalid tag names - can't start with digits ([[w3]: STag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-STag) ==> [[w3]: Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) ==> [[w3]: NameStartChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar))

In order to illustrate this I prepared an *XML* sample containing all (4) combinations of the above 2 bullets (each can be *on* / *off*).

*malformed.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <1ELEMENT0> text 1ELEMENT0 <\1ELEMENT0>
    <ELEMENT0> text ELEMENT0 <\ELEMENT0>
    <11ELEMENT1> text 11ELEMENT1 </11ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT1> text ELEMENT1 </ELEMENT1>
</root>
```

As can be easily seen, only the last node is OK, and *etree* would raise `ParseError` if any of the 1<sup>st</sup> 3 nodes is present and uncommented.

*code.py*:

```
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


FILE_NAME_0 = "malformed.xml"
FILE_NAME_1 = "wellformed.xml"

END_TAG_BSLASH_PAT = re.compile("<(\\\\).+>")
TAG_DIGIT_PAT = re.compile("</{0,1}(\d+)[^>]+>")


def parse_xml(file_name):
    tree = ET.parse(file_name)
    root_node = tree.getroot()
    for child_node in list(root_node):
        print("{:s} - [{:s}]".format(child_node.tag, child_node.text))


def _process_match(match):
    text = match.group()
    digits_text = match.group(1)
    idx = text.find(digits_text)
    return "_".join([text[:idx], text[idx:]])


def convert_xml_file(in_file_name=FILE_NAME_0, out_file_name=FILE_NAME_1):
    with open(in_file_name) as fin:
        text = fin.read()
        end_tag_bslash_text = re.sub(END_TAG_BSLASH_PAT, lambda x: x.group().replace(x.group(1), "/", 1), text)
        #print(end_tag_bslash_text)
        tag_digit_text = re.sub(TAG_DIGIT_PAT, _process_match, end_tag_bslash_text)
        print(tag_digit_text)
        with open(out_file_name, "w") as fout:
            fout.write(tag_digit_text)


def main():
    #parse_xml(FILE_NAME_0)
    convert_xml_file()
    parse_xml(FILE_NAME_1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- Tries to convert the above malformed *XML* in a ***syntactically** correct* form, by fixing the 2 mentioned errors (**only**)
- `parse_xml` - dummy function that parses an *XML* file and dumps the tag and text of root node's children
- `convert_xml_file` - does the actual conversion:

  - uses a combination of [[Python]: Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and string operations

    - I know, it is kind of poor, it's definitely possible to do it elegantly using just *regexp*
    - Pattern matching is also poor (e.g. possible *SPACE*s between `<` (or `>`) and the tag are not considered, if such space occurs that tag will not be processed)
    - It might replace more than it should; it works on simple *XML*s, but if they tend to be more complex it might replace genuine `\`s (e.g. in a *CDATA* section)
  - First, it replaces the `\`s in the end tags
  - Then, it adds an `_` (*underscore*) in front of every tag (start and end) that starts with a digit
  - Writes the resulting text into another file (to be used later)
  - It opens files in **text** mode, which is also a bad thing since, they might have different encodings
- `_process_match`: helper function (used by the previous) to correct the tags starting with digits (as it's a bit more complex operation and a `lambda` would be hard to read)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048571060>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <root>
>     <_1ELEMENT0> text 1ELEMENT0 </_1ELEMENT0>
>     <ELEMENT0> text ELEMENT0 </ELEMENT0>
>     <_11ELEMENT1> text 11ELEMENT1 </_11ELEMENT1>
>     <ELEMENT1> text ELEMENT1 </ELEMENT1>
> </root>
>
> _1ELEMENT0 - [ text 1ELEMENT0 ]
> ELEMENT0 - [ text ELEMENT0 ]
> _11ELEMENT1 - [ text 11ELEMENT1 ]
> ELEMENT1 - [ text ELEMENT1 ]
> ```

**Final notes**:

- As many noticed, this is handling the effect rather than the cause, or "*hiding the dirt under the carpet*". It's a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*) meant just to get you past this point
- *XML* might contain other *syntactic* errors
- Even if the file is now syntactically correct, there could also be *semantic* errors
- Continuing in this direction is a clear recipe for disaster. The proper fix should go **wherever the *XML* is being generated** (this is simply common sense)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an XML file.

Given that the format of the file is garbage, are you sure the content isn't garbage too? I wouldn't want to work with data from such an untrustworthy source.

If you want to parse this data you will need to work out what rules it follows. If those rules are something fairly similar to XML rules then it might be that converting it to XML and then parsing the XML is a reasonable way to go about this; if not, you might be better off writing a parser from scratch.

But before you do so, try to persuade the people responsible for this nonsense of the benefits of conforming to standards.